# how to append <dds></dds> tag by click special word in paragraph for document.querySelector('dds');

Tags: html, jquery

<p  >This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.

</p>

Please help me I want to create tag a word when I click

on it

```
Again when the second word is clicked
  Delete the first word tag and create the second word tag
```

var card = document.querySelector('dds');

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use a `span` for each word and give them a click event by wrapping it in the tag you need

```js
const test = document.querySelector('#test');
const html = test.innerHTML;
const words = html.split(/ /);
let newHtml = '';

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  newHtml += '<span>' + words[i] + '</span> ';
}
test.innerHTML = newHtml;

test.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.parentElement.nodeName !== 'DDS') {
      const wrapper = document.createElement('dds');
      // insert wrapper before el in the DOM tree
      e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, e.target);
      // move el into wrapper
      wrapper.appendChild(e.target);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
dds{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<p id="test">This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.
</p>
```